# Hash every element of a list of strings in a pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, hash

So I have a dataframe like this

```
   customer     location       trip_len
0     a      ['1', '2', '3']      3
1     b      ['4', '5']           2
```

And I am trying to hash, for every row, every element on the list of strings on the column 'location' in order to improve efficiency in my model. How would this be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "hash" in this context? It'd help if you could [edit] to describe what you actually want to achieve please. eg: after this "hash"ing... what would your DF look like or what would you want to be doing with it? Providing more context here would be fabulous - thanks.

Comment: Do you want to _categorize_ your values? Perhaps something like [sklearn's ordinal encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are not natively hashable as those are mutable objects. If only storage is of interest converting to a `tuple` is an option.

```
df.location = df.location.apply(lambda locations: hash(tuple(locations)))
```